# GAE datastore key usage for referenceproperty prior to .put()

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

This seems like a simple question, however wanted something more clear than what I'm doing currently:

Given tables like these (example only):

```
class People(db.Model):
    FirstName  = db.StringProperty(multiline=False,required=True)
    LastName   = db.StringProperty(multiline=False,required=True)
class Animals(db.Model):
    AnimalName = db.StringProperty(multiline=False,required=True)
class SpiritAnimal(db.Model):
    Person     = db.ReferenceProperty(Candidates,required=True)
    Animal     = db.ReferenceProperty(Candidates,required=True)
```

There exists a way to fill in 'Person' and 'Animal' using queries to the other two tables like so (example only):

```
# Query for some person(s)
query = People.all()
query.filter('FirstName', 'Patrick')
query.get()
for person in query:
    newSpiritAnimal = SpiritAnimal(
        Person     = person,
        Animal     = animal # Assuming pulled previously
    )
    newSpiritAnimal.put()
```

Also you can just grab keys, however here is where my question comes into play:

Based off a query such as above, can you just pull the key and use later? Of course you can, but what's the best method to do so?

Let's think about this example:

```
for person in query:
    key_for_later_use = person.key()
```

Now we can use:

```
Person = key_for_later_use
```

One would assume correct? Except this person.key() object doesn't seem to be doing the trick so I looked into it more:

```
str(person.key())
```

This provides a key that looks like what you would see in the GAE SDK Console when viewing the 'Datastore Viewer' thus potentially useful, but not having luck with that either.

What's the best way to grab a key off a query, potentially when iterating via for loop?

I've been trying to offload datastore queries by creating a list which I check for something existing, then grab from another list the key:

```
people_list = [] # Assume populated with 'FirstName'
people_list_keys = [] # Assume populated with person.key()
if 'Patrick' in people_list:
    patrick_key = people_list_keys[people.index('Patrick')]
```

However person.key() doesn't really work, str() around that looks right but doesn't work right.. and by that I mean using that as SpiritAnimal.Person on insert for the ReferenceProperty.

Thoughts?

Oh and I'm seriously not making a SpiritAnimal application, this is all just examples ;)

Comment: I'm dismayed to learn after reading all that that you aren't actually making a spirit animal application. Would be cool.

Comment: Can you post the error message? I don't know what you mean that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a disconnect elsewhere, I ran this code:

```
    People(FirstName="Patrick", LastName="Doe").put()

    animal = Animals(AnimalName="Tiger").put()
    people_list = [] 
    people_list_keys = []

    query = People.all()
    query.filter('FirstName', 'Patrick')
    query.get()

    for person in query:
        people_list.append(person.FirstName)
        people_list_keys.append(person.key())

    patrick_key = people_list_keys[people_list.index('Patrick')]

    newSpiritAnimal = SpiritAnimal(
    Person     = patrick_key,
    Animal     = animal
    )
    newSpiritAnimal.put()
```

And the Spirit Animal was 'put' no problem. I don't quite get what your trying to do. Perhaps a little more explanation and I can help a bit more.